# 'String#include?' for multiple patterns

Tags: ruby

From a text, how can I exclude certain keywords listed in an array?

Here's my loop:

```
@entries.each do |entry|
entry.title.include? ("bad_word")
  (do nothing)
else
  puts entry.title
```

I also tried:

```
if ["bad_word"].include? entry.title
```

The first bit of code works as long as I only specify a single word. `"bad_word" || "naughty_word"` only picks up the first. The second bit of code seems to filter nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
/bad_word|naughty_word|another_bad_word/i
```

As an example:

```
"Here's a bad_word" =~ /bad_word|naughty_word/i
# 9
"Here's a naughty_word" =~ /bad_word|naughty_word/i
# 9
"Here's a perfectly fine title" =~ /bad_word|naughty_word/i
# nil
```

One potential problem is that you'll get false positives:

```
"He has skills" =~ /bad_word|naughty_word|kill/i
# 8
```

You could try to solve it with word boundaries:

```
"He has skills" =~ /\b(bad_word|naughty_word|kill)\b/i
# nil
```

But then you'll get false negatives:

```
"A kills B" =~ /\b(bad_word|naughty_word|kill)\b/i
# nil
```

You could try to solve it with :

```
"A kills B" =~ /\b(bad_word|naughty_word|kill[a-z]{,2})\b/i
# 2
"He has skills" =~ /\b(bad_word|naughty_word|kill[a-z]{,2})\b/i
# nil
```

Still, the logic is so fuzzy with word detection that you cannot find a perfect solution to your problem.

Comment: Are there any significant performance differences between regex vs unless?

Comment: @freehunter my solution filters titles if they have bad words inside. The other solution filters the title only if it is a bad word.

Comment: Your regex is working perfectly for me. I'm marking this as the answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: @freehunter: Updated for a bit more robustness.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply print the title *unless* it is a bad word, just like in this snippet:

```
<% unless ["bad_word1", "bad_word2"].include? entry.title %>
  # print the title
<% else %>
  # do sth else
<% end %>
```

Perhaps even more straightforward (the `unless`-`else` logic may be confusing):

```
<% if ["bad_word1", "bad_word2"].exclude? entry.title %>
  # print the title
<% else %>
  # do sth else
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unless gives me the same results as "if ["bad_word"].include? entry.title", it doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't print anything either.

Comment: You only check if the title is a bad word. Not if it includes a bad word.

Comment: To give a more concrete example, a headline might read "16 year old killed in car crash". Pretty depressing, I want to filter that out. So anything that includes "kill" should be suppressed. "Local man murdered during mugging" is another example, anything that includes "murder" should be suppressed.

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood the question. In this case you can use a regexp as suggested by @EricDuminil which is probably the cleanest solution. You can also go for something like `["bad_word1", "bad_word2"].any? { |word| word.include?(entry.title) }`. As for the problem of not being able to print, try returning the `entry.title` itself instead of using `puts entry.title`, as `puts` always returns `nil`.